# WPF TreeView with right alignment values issue

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to make a TreeView with items that have some counts etc. right aligned when shown.  I came across the following on SO, but I can't figure out why my output is not actually a TreeView, there are not arrows (expanders or whatever) and no indentation etc, like the image shows it is.  There are some things left out in the description of the solution.  Apparently they used a List of 'MyTreeItem'. but I don't see how that would create any hierarchical relationship.  So i just get a list basically, albeit with the properties shown how i want.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:TreeView"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
        <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Height="16" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="16">
                            <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898">
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterY="3" CenterX="3"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="StretchTreeViewItemStyle"
TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchTreeViewItemStyle}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:MyTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Here's the code=behind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            Items = new List<MyTreeItem>();

            MyTreeItem one = new MyTreeItem();
            one.Display = "Level 1";
            one.Value = "Level1";
            Items.Add(one);

            MyTreeItem two = new MyTreeItem();
            two.Display = "Volvo";
            two.Value = "Volvo";
            Items.Add(two);

            MyTreeItem three = new MyTreeItem();
            three.Display = "New";
            three.Value = "New";
            Items.Add(three);

            MyTreeItem four = new MyTreeItem();
            four.Display = "Old";
            four.Value = "Old";
            Items.Add(four);


        }

       public List<MyTreeItem> Items
        { get; set; }


    }
    public class MyTreeItem
    {
        public string Display
        { get; set; }
        public string Value
        { get;set; }
    }
}
```

And here's image of how its supposed to look according to the post:
[image]
But this is what I get:
[image]

How do i fix this?  What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duh i forgot to actually add the children, so i just had to make List Items inside the class so now it's recursive